# Chrome Extension Jquery .on Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm just getting into some chrome extension development, and have came across the following bug - I have a .on event defined for a button in the popup.html file that defines my extension, but it does not trigger (or throw an error in the extension inspector) when clicked. If ran in another envrionment (such as jsfiddle or codepen), it works exactly as planned.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <textarea id = "names" rows="4" cols="50">Enter the user's name</textarea>
    <button id ="close">Close</button>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$('#close').on('click',function(){
$('#names').val('works');
});
```

Comment: You probably need to wrap your JS code in `$(function(){ })` (or `$(document).ready(function(){ })`).

Comment: the $(function(){}) was all it needed, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delay your JavaScript code until the DOM is ready.

```
$(function(){
    $('#close').on('click',function(){
        $('#names').val('works');
    });
});
```

`$(function(){ })` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ })`.